# how to make radius for outline property

Tags: css

```css
.myElement {
  width: 200px;
  height: 100px;
  border: 3px solid #0064d2;
  outline: solid red;
  border-radius: 30px;
}
```

```html
<div class="myElement"></div>
```

I want to create a rounded blue border with rectangular red outline but border-radius impacts on outline and makes it round

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use an `::after` to separate the outline from the border:

You can change the size by altering the percentage, i've used `80%` of the parent as example.

To center the element, use `transform translate` of half of the remaining space

```css
.myElement {
    width: 200px;
    height: 100px;
    outline: solid red;
    padding: 10px;
    position: relative;
}

.myElement::after {
    content: "";
    border: 3px solid #0064d2;
    border-radius: 30px;
    display: inline-block;
    width: 80%;
    height: 80%;
    transform: translate(10%,10%);
}
```

```html
<div class="myElement"></div>
```

Comment: thank you for you solution it works, but if it has text it goes at bottom a little
when it comes to <div class="myElement">123666</div>